# PHP execute asyncronous php script in shell command doesn't work on bitnami LAMP AWS

Tags: php, linux, shell, asynchronous, amazon-web-services

on my local machine I execute the following:

```
exec('sudo nohup '.PHP_BINDIR.'/php '.ROOT.'/index.php controller=imports action=import id=12 > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

where "ROOT" is a constant with the complete path.

Everything works fine and the script is executed asyncronously with no problems.

When I run the same script on production environment (a bitnami LAMP stack running on AWS) instead: if I run it directly from the terminal it works, when I run it from php it doesn't.

I have nothing in the apache error_log and if I run it with shell_exec the returned value is NULL.

If I try to execute a different script from php (like exec('whoami')) it works, so I don't think is a permissions thing.

I also tried replacing php command with php-cli, nothing changes.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For debugging, try running `sudo -u www-data env -i bash` to get a fresh shell running as www-data (replace if your php script runs as a different user). Try your sudo command in this new shell and see if it still works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. If I run in this new shell as you suggested it actually doesn't work! But I don't get any error, it only seems to be "stucked". Because if I run the same command after a while the precedent one results as "Stopped". Any suggestions?

Comment: And if I run directly php command (without nohup) I get "The program 'php' is currently not installed.  To run 'php' please ask your administrator to install the package 'php5-cli'"... I think that's the error!

Comment: Run your command as posted but with `mylog.txt` instead of `/dev/null`, then look at `mylog.txt` to see what the errors are

Comment: I find what was printed "The program 'php' is currently not installed.  To run 'php' please ask your administrator to install the package 'php5-cli'". But If I try to install with apt-get I am prompted to insert the user (daemon) password, which I don't know (and it's not empty and it's not *).

Comment: Made to install it as a root user, now in mylog.txt I found "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in ..... bla bla", but how that's possible???

Comment: Are you running `sudo nohup /path/to/php ...` or just `php ...`?

Comment: Two problems: 1) if I run it with `sudo` it asks me `daemon` user password, which as I said I don't have (and it's neither empty nor `*`) 2) if I run it without I find inside mylog.txt `bash: /opt/bitnami/lampstack-linux-x64/output/php/bin/php: No such file or directory` that it's true, it's not a directory, and I don't know why it tells it's there, I retrieve that path with the `PHP_BINDIR` constant